# Laravel App Development Advice

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am in the process of planing to build an app and have a few questions that I would like to get 100% in my head.

What is the best method from your prospective in regards to updating code and going between live/maintenance mode sites?

What do you recommend for Authentication?

How would you handle cacheing and CDN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to start, I'd like to say welcome to the newest version of laravel (released apx 3 weeks ago).

Second: authentication is handled completely for you in this version of laravel, and it is well [documented](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/) for you to customize.

As far as switching from live / maintenence mode, as always we suggest keeping a live Repo and a branch for development. May we suggest using [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) coupling it with our [forge](https://forge.laravel.com/) service in order to ease deploying and setting up your servers!

As far as a CDN goes, that's all based on your experience. I don't recommend one over the other because my opinion would be biased and the current version is fairly new, so any packages/dependencies for previous versions would need to be updated and/or tested for compatibility  :)

I hope this helps!