# Creating an Expiry URL after a time frame

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have been looking at cloudinary.com for a project I am building and it does everything I want to a point.

One of the things that I need to create a link that expires after 30 days.

Is this possible? or will I have to write an internal function that gets all the data and creates its own link in the db and maybe a cron job to check for expired links?

Comment: What version of laravel are you using? 5.2?

Comment: @DerekPollard Will be the latest I am currently thinking out loud

Comment: Okay, I'm on the laravel dev team. I'd suggest setting a controller method in routes and passing in a get parameter and checking it against a stored model timestamp.

Comment: You can simply use `timestamp` to set a conditional action for it.

Comment: @DerekPollard Was my mind of thinking you may also be interested to read my other question I have open

Comment: Shoot me the link and I'll read it :)

Comment: @DerekPollard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625048/laravel-app-development-advice Using Google and looking over fourms is good but it gets conflicting with no straight answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there wont be need of Cron jobs.You can set some token with your URL and security token should be in your DB with date time. So that you can find 30 days peroid and throw expire message.